# jquery plugin get and set message

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to write a plugin that can be used in a way similar to this: This isnt really what i'd use it for but this is the start of my test to get a full understanding.

Html:

```
<div id="div"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
var plugin = $('#div').plugin();

plugin.message.set('hi');
alert(plugin.message.get());
```

What i'm missing is the ability to create one instance of the plugin on the element, and use it to get and set properties:

I'm assuming i'd set up a bit like below, can someone fill in the gaps please?  I'm not sure how to call the method 'get' for example and how to pass the arguments through...

```
$.fn.plugin = function () {
    var target = this;

    methods: {

        var message = {
            get: function () {
                return $(target).text();
            },
            set: function () {
                $(target).text(message);
            },
        };

    };

};
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a commonly used basic skeleton of a jQuery plugin :

```
(function($)
{
    var parameters = 
    {
        myDefault: "default"
    };

    var methods = {
        init : function(options) {
            return this.each(function() {
                parameters = $.extend(parameters, options);
            });
        },
        myMethod: function(){}
    };

    $.fn.myPlugin = function(methodOrOptions) {
        if ( methods[methodOrOptions] ) {
            return methods[ methodOrOptions ].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
        } else if ( typeof methodOrOptions === 'object' || ! methodOrOptions ) {
            // Default to "init"
            return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
        } else {
            $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.myPlugin' );
        }    
    };

})(jQuery);
```

Use it this way :

**init**

```
$('#myDiv').myPlugin({
    myDefault: "override"
});
```

This will call the `init` method, which in this case changes the default parameters.

**call a method**

```
$('#myDiv').myPlugin('myMethod');
```

See more here : http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/